# Subscribing to the Stack Overflow podcast with Zune player

Tags: support, podcast

What is a/the URL of the Stack Overflow podcast feed that works with Microsoft's Zune software/player?

Comment: *shudders* I got a zune for free as part of a deal for a laptop...I am typing on the laptop right now and I have no idea where the zune is.

Comment: The only Z*** I've ever seen was my brother's 4GB black which stopped working after a couple weeks and he had to throw it away. I **did** tell him to grab an iPod but he said it runs XNA. Poor kid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I felt bad mocking you for having a Zune, so I did a quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22stack+overflow%22+podcast+zune) and found in the [comments of SO Podcast #5](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/podcast-5/) that someone was [having trouble](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/podcast-5/#comment-310) subscribing with their Zune. However, it sounds like once the person [upgraded to the latest version](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/podcast-5/#comment-330) there was no problem. Do you have at least Zune 2.5? If not, you should try upgrading to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: What is the URL of the podcast feed?

Comment: I think this is it http://blog.stackoverflow.com/?feed=podcast

Comment: Thanks Kyle, that link (blog.stackoverflow.com/?feed=podcast) worked like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site to generate Zune-friendly one-click subscribe links:

http://www.zunepodcastsubscription.com/

Using that, here's the one-click Zune link (although I have no idea if the SO code will allow Zune-style links):

zune://subscribe/?StackOverflow=https://blog.stackoverflow.com/?feed=podcast

Update: nope, it sure doesn't.  Not surprised.  Well, you can build a local html page with an a href tag pointing to that Zune URL above and it should work.